# Multipart HTTP Response vs Zip File For API Response

Tags: http, zip, multipartform-data, multipart, api-design

If I want to return multiple files in one HTTP response from my API because my clients have **very** low bandwidth and bad internet connectivity, what is my best option for sending them to the client?

Should I use a Multipart HTTP response or zip up all my files and return those? I realize that Multipart HTTP responses are not recommended for browsers but I am talking about an API where I control the client.

Comment: I've come to the exact same question. Have you figured out what's the best solution? What did you choose? Thanks.

Comment: @darefilz I tried setting up multipart but it is a bit of extra work (I'm using ASP.NET Core which has API's for this) and my client developer was not too keen on it (Java). In the end, I settled on requesting each file individually. It's slower but I'm hoping HTTP 2.0 will sort that when we make the move to it, in the mean time I'm making multiple (two due to low bandwidth) requests at a time. From an API perspective, I think it's fine to use multipart. I hope that helps you!