# How to send a collection of files + JSON data to the client side

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, api-design

In my ASP.NET Core Web API I have an entity Idea:

```
  public class Idea
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? MainPhotoId { get; set; }
    public Photo MainPhoto { get; set; }

    public int? MainVideoId { get; set; }
    public Video MainVideo { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Audio> Audios { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> DocumentsAboutTheIdea { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfPublishing { get; set; }
}
public class Photo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
(the different media-type classes are equivalent)
```

When the client makes a Post request for creating the Idea he sends the information about it along with all the media-files (I am using IFormFile and IFormFileCollection) and while saving them on the server I set the Url property to match their location. But in the Get request I want to send the files (not Urls).

Here is the Get action which now returns only one file (mainPhoto) without any JSON and without any other media-files:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        var query = await unitOfWork.IdeaRepository.GetByIdAsync(id, includeProperties: "Owner,MainPhoto,MainVideo,Photos,Videos,Audios,DocumentsAboutTheIdea");
        if (query != null)
        {
            string webRootPath = hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var path = string.Concat(webRootPath, query.MainPhoto.Url);
            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
return NotFound();
}
```

So in a Get request I want to send to the client side (an Angular app) some of the information about the Idea in a JSON-format ALONG WITH different (NOT ONE) media-files associated with it. My goal is to make the client side get it all so that it can then show them on the page of the info about the Idea. But I cannot figure out the approach for this. Is there a way to achieve this? Or there is another (better) way of interacting with the client side to transfer all the required data? I tried to find information on this topic but couldn't find any.

Comment: According to your data model, the "photos" and "videos" and whatnot are just the ID and URL for each item.  Is that what you mean?  Is that not being sent to the client?  Are you trying to send something else?  Where?

Comment: @David When the client makes a Post request for creating the Idea he sends the information about it along with all the media-files (I am using IFormFile and IFormFileCollection) and while saving them on the server I set the Url property to match their location. But in the Get request I want to send the files (not Urls). My goal is to make the client side get all the media-files of an Idea so it can then show them on the page of the info about the Idea. But I cannot figure out the approach for this. Updated the question with the Get action (which is far from what I need).

Comment: What format do you want to send them in?  You can include them as properties in the JSON with the files' byte data base-64-encoded, for example.  Or you could send the data you have and then the client-side code can initiate separate requests for all of the referenced resources in the URLs.  But if you're expecting to send "files" then you'd have to package them all together into a single "file", such as a ZIP file.  A response can only contain one type of data.

Comment: @David I guess the easiest way is the option to  include them as properties in the JSON with the files' base-64-encoded byte data. I was thinking of something like Multipart responce (but wasn't sure if it can be made at all or at least it didn't sound like something "doable"). I also thought of making separate requests for all of the resources but it seems to me like a not very efficient solution (or am I wrong?). And talking about ZIP files - this option is usually used to send files only,without  the other data (like my Idea properties), right?Anyway, thank you for your structured response!

Comment: I'm not aware of any multi-part response, only form requests.  I could be wrong though, maybe it's just never come up or is a rare edge case.  Separate requests might be less efficient in one way, but more efficient in another?  If the UI quickly gets back the list of items and displays something, then the user sees progress as each item individually loads, that could be better than waiting much longer for everything at once.  And yes, for a ZIP file basically the JSON would be another "file" therein, and ZIP parsing in JavaScript might be not fun.

Comment: @David I don't know much about the multipart response too - just saw a question on SO mentioning it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139818/multipart-http-response-vs-zip-file-for-api-response?rq=1) but it was also mentioned that it might not be the recommended way. Yes, you are right, thanks for mentioning about the separate requests. So, the first too options (sending files' base-64-encoded byte data as part of JSON request and the option with separate requests) seem to be the best ones to choose. Thanks for the help!